# Spring MVC + Web services + Hibernate project structure

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, architecture

in .net it is possible to create webservices, asp.net MVC, ORM, DTO, BAL as  different projects so that we can reuse them nicely. For this college project I have been force to use j2ee and I am wondering how to do this layering. Is it possible to create hibernate as a different project? or how should I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know .net at all, but you can start by creating multimodule maven project in eclipse.

- 1 module will contain you Entities and Dao and procude a jar,
- 1 module will contain @Controller and object related to your web service and
  produce a war or ear.